# Authentication String of Root User on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and have finally reached quite close to the solution as pointed out in this article:

https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/

Especially this line:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'test';
```

But, when I run this on my command line I get the following:

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'test';

ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'
```

Further down below in this article there is a comment by someone:

---

If the commande `“ALTER USER ‘root’@’localhost’ IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY ‘test’;” doesn’t work you can try :`

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD(‘test’), plugin = ‘mysql_native_password’ WHERE User = ‘root’ AND Host = ‘localhost’;
```

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

---

When I try this I get the following:

mysql>

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD(‘test’), plugin = ‘mysql_native_password’ WHERE User = ‘root’ AND Host = ‘localhost’;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '‘root’' in 'where clause'
```

---

I can see the problem that my root user has no password set.  That is why I cannot login as root and I have combed through all the threads here discussing that without any solution.

Here are some warnings that were helpful to me to find the above resources.

[Root user has no authentication_string set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prota.png)

https://gyazo.com/fef2073150114ae487f6a0b3b6cf3f96

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

---

Additional information based on questions asked in the comments:

mysql> show create user root@'localhost';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation SHOW CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'

Problem that I'm trying to solve is to add a password for root.

Right now I have to run mysql using the following sudo mysql

I can't do something like mysql -u root -p

I get the following output:

tkhara@sandbox:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Because there seems to be no password set for the root user.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? To set a password or add the authentication string? Can you execute `show create user root@'localhost';` and post the output? Also what version of MySQL?

Comment: SQL version is 5.7.22 and I have added the information you have asked for to the post.

Comment: The quote marks look weird in your syntax dont use ‘root’ use 'root'

Comment: Thank you. That was one of the things that was wrong with it. But, despite that, I'm still not able to set a password for root.